# eBay API exclude countries using ExcludeShipToLocation in AddItem request

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to define list of countries excluded from shipping in the `AddItem` request using `ExcludeShipToLocation` in the sandbox environment. Request goes through, item is listed but can not see the excluded in countries in the shipping options.

I tried

```
<ShipToRegistrationCountry>true</ShipToRegistrationCountry>
```

and

```
<ExcludeShipToLocation>[two letter country code]</ExcludeShipToLocation>
```

as pointed out in documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code i can't see wich field you used anyway i can tell you what is the simple rule of shipping system.
You have to chose where to ship with 
-> ShipToLocation

and set something like 
 ShipToLocation -> EuropeanUnion

Now by using ExcludeShipToLocation set rest of the world an either place in europe where yuo don't want to ship, for example:

```
$extra_exclude = "<ExcludeShipToLocation>Asia</ExcludeShipToLocation>";
$extra_exclude .= "<ExcludeShipToLocation>Central America and Caribbean</ExcludeShipToLocation>";
$extra_exclude .= "<ExcludeShipToLocation>Middle East</ExcludeShipToLocation>";
$extra_exclude .= "<ExcludeShipToLocation>North America</ExcludeShipToLocation>";
$extra_exclude .= "<ExcludeShipToLocation>Oceania</ExcludeShipToLocation>";
$extra_exclude .= "<ExcludeShipToLocation>Southeast Asia</ExcludeShipToLocation>";
$extra_exclude .= "<ExcludeShipToLocation>South America</ExcludeShipToLocation>";
$extra_exclude .= "<ExcludeShipToLocation>AL</ExcludeShipToLocation>";
$extra_exclude .= "<ExcludeShipToLocation>AD</ExcludeShipToLocation>";
<!-- And so on -->
```

This is actually working like a charm for me and i still adding items with long exclusion list. I have had to get crazy to made it work but it is perfect now.